# Declaring multiple variables based on data list

Tags: list, powershell, if-statement

I have a list of numbers coming in and I need to declare that multiple variables as true based on the first character of a set of items in a list.

This is in no way an actual example, but here's a scenario. Here are a set of items:

```
A1
A2
A4
B3
B5
```

I need the script to look through this list and if it any of the first characters start with an A then `$A = true`. And/or if it finds any starting with B then `$B = true`. And if it doesn't find any that start with C then `$C = false`.

I need the script to check for each letter and then pretty much report back if it found any values that started with that letter.

I know this is kind of a confusing post, so please reply back if there are any questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Initialize your variables as `$false`:

```
$A = $false
$B = $false
$C = $false
...
```

Then iterate over your list and use a [`switch`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_switch?view=powershell-3.0) statement to set variables to `$true` if a list item starts with a particular character:

```
$list | ForEach-Object {
    switch -wildcard ($_) {
        'a*' { $A = $true }
        'b*' { $B = $true }
        'c*' { $C = $true }
        ...
    }
}
```

Or, as Bruce Payette pointed out in the comments, just pass the list into the `switch` statement directly:

```
switch -wildcard ($list) {
    'a*' { $A = $true }
    'b*' { $B = $true }
    'c*' { $C = $true }
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ansgar was faster, so a different approach

```
$List = ("A1","A2","A4","B3","B5")

"A","B","C" | ForEach-Object {
    "Checking {0}" -f $_
    if ($List -match "^$_"){
        "$($_):True"
        Set-Variable -Name "$_" -Value $True
    } else {
        "$($_):False"
        Set-Variable -Name "$_" -Value $False
    }
}
```

Sample output:

```
Checking A
A:True
Checking B
B:True
Checking C
C:False
```

Answer (score 0):

I'll give you another option, one where you don't have to manually type out 26 cases.

```
ForEach($Char in (65..90|%{[char]$_})){
    Set-Variable -Name $Char -Value ([bool]($List -match "^$char"))
    "$Char found: " + (Get-Variable $Char).Value
}
```

This iterates A-Z, and checks if anything in the list matches that for the first letter, and evaluates the result as True/False. Then it assigns that result to a variable for that character, and displays the results.